# Please reopen this question, I can make a good answer

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

Please re-open [What was the most popular operating system on the PDP-11 computers?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17652/what-was-the-most-popular-operating-system-on-the-pdp-11-computers/). I would make a partial answer (albeit, extended) regarding the PDP-11 analogs in the USSR.

Comment: What do you mean by “make good review”? (Post a good answer?) Though I'm unsure why this question was closed in the first place, to be honest.

Comment: This very question doesn’t look too promising as to your ability to write a good answer there…

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I would make a partial answer (albeit, extended) regarding the PDP-11 analogs in the USSR.

Comment: Given that the question is specifically about PDP-11s, I don’t think an answer about PDP-11 analogs in the USSR would be relevant. *However*, as a general rule, it is perfectly OK to write a self-answered Q&A: if you have information you feel would be useful to share here, and it doesn’t address an existing Q exactly, you can write a new Q and answer that.

Comment: The question is already calling for opinions by nature, extending it to SU computers would not really improve that - despite being interesting. Opening another question will as well only make sense if there is any kind of dependable data. Just mentioning applications for an arbitrary system (like you did for  [the FD question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/23637/6659) ) is not helpful at all.

Comment: As expected, the Answer uses only a short assumption about the PDP for a lengthy praise of the BK010 series. As much I like those machines, it's not an answer to the question but only a hook to evangelize about the BK010 series.